# Explanation regarding `showmount -e` needed - what does "@" mean?

Tags: linux, networking, nfs

As stated in the title: What does the `@...` in the output below mean? I don't think they are hostnames, because I think the `@`-sign is reserved for mailing. Normally there stands a IP-subnet or simply an IP-address - but nothing is the case here. I also know I can put hostnames in there, but I don't think I could put such `@...` into the hosts file to restrict the access to only some IPs... Sooo, what is this?

```
glaforge@enterprise: showmount -e [REMOVED]
Export list for [REMOVED]:
[REMOVED]   *
[REMOVED]   @somenamea,@somenameb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list of exports shown by `showmount -e` any names with an `@` are netgroups, not individual hosts.

A netgroup is a list of hosts. They're typically defined in `/etc/netgroup` on the NFS server (but could also be in NIS, LDAP, etc. depending on how `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is configured).

Using netgroups to define your exports saves a lot of typing compared to exporting to each host separately. (I find that it reduces the chances of making typos. Or if I do make a typo in one of my exports, I'll find it faster as it'll affect all the machines in the netgroup rather than just one machine.)

## Example

On my NFS server I could have the following netgroups defined in `/net/netgroup`:

```
nuts    (walnut,,) (almond,,) (pistachio,,) (hazelnut,,)
flowers (rose,,) (tulip,,) (iris,,)
```

Each entry in a netgroup is defined as a tuple of `(hostname, user, NIS domain)` but NFS only cares about the hostname so just leave the other parts blank. The NIS domain is not the same thing as a DNS domain. If you need to specify a full DNS name, e.g., foo.example.com, put it all in the host part: `(foo.example.com,,)`

And then my `exports` file could look like this:

```
/vol/home    @nuts(rw) @flowers(rw)
/vol/web     @nuts(rw)
/vol/dns     @nuts(ro) almond(rw)
```

Now the hosts in the `flowers` netgroup can mount `home` read-write but can't access `web` or `dns`. The host `almond` has read-write access to everything, but the rest of the machines in the `nuts` netgroup only have read-only access to `dns`.

If I were to run `showmount -e` it would look something like this:

```
% showmount -e
Export list for example.com:
/vol/home @nuts,@flowers
/vol/web  @nuts
/vol/dns  @nuts,almond
```

Comment: Sorry for rejecting your edit correction. I messed that one up. You were right! Thank you for your really good explanation!!!